# Linking to a library prior to installing that library

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, libraries

### How to point the linker to a temporary path during the build?

Context:
Link to a library that is not installed but will be in the future

```cmake
...

set(LIBS_TO_BE_INSTALLED)
   libA.so
   libB.so
) 

set(FUTURE_LIB_PATH
    /usr/lib/future/path
) # Libraries are found here if installed

set(TEMPORARY_LIB_PATH
   /temporary/path
) # Libraries are found here before installing

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED $SRCS $HDRS)
link_directories(AFTER $FUTURE_LIB_PATH) #this works if libs are installed
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBS_TO_BE_INSTALLED})

...
```

How `ldd` output should look:

```bash
$ ldd ${PROJECT_NAME}.so
    ...
    libA.so.X => /usr/lib/future/path/libA.so.X
    libB.so.Y => /usr/lib/future/path/libB.so.Y
    ...
```

However it doesn't work when trying to use temporary path:

```cmake
link_directories(AFTER $TEMPORARY_LIB_PATH)
```

Fails with error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX shared library ${PROJCET_NAME}.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibA: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibB: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```cmake
set(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH true)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${TEMPORARY_LIB_PATH})
```

`ldd` output *before* future libraries are installed:

```bash
$ ldd ${PROJECT_NAME}.so
    ...
    libA.so.X => not found
    libB.so.Y => not found
    ...
```